# Mock private/ static methods with jmockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jacoco, jmockit

I tried to use **jmockit 1.18** to mock static method but I had worries with Code coverage. The error I got was:

> java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while
>   instrumenting class org/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier

I am using **jacoco agent 0.6.3.201306030806** and **EclEmma core 2.2.1.201306092145**.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of JaCoCo (before [0.7.3](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/changes.html) - search for "jmockit" in the linked page) would run into conflict with other bytecode modifying tools (such as JMockit).

So, if you upgrade EclEmma to a version which uses JaCoCo 0.7.3+ it should be fine.

On the other hand, the `IllegalClassFormatException` you got points to JUnit's `RunNotifier` class, which JMockit modifies at runtime (for integration purposes), but JaCoCo *should not* be modifying. So, here you probably need to *exclude* such classes from JaCoCo instrumentation (see JaCoCo/EclEmma documentation).

Answer (score -2):

> I had worries with Code coverage

You may experience this with almost any mocking framework that allowes for mocking `private`/`final` classes and `static`/`private`/`final` members. The reason is that the mocking framework alters the *byte code* at **runtime** of the actual test whereas the coverage tool alters the byte code **before** the start of the tests.

The better approach is to change your code so that it does not use static access to  members and not making methods `final` (in general). Furthermore if you properly implement *Separation of Concerns*, *Single Responsibility*, Single Layer of Abstraction* and *dependency injection* you'd have an easier job to write test...

Comment: Rather than 1) making wild assumptions about the reasons for some technical problem, 2) recommending that developers bend their code to limitations of specific testing tools, 3) promoting bad design (since proper use of `final` is important in good API design - see "Effective Java" book for example), and 4) throwing buzzwords around, you could perhaps actually try to provide a correct and helpful answer to the problem at hand (see my answer for example)...

Comment: @Rogério  **1)** can you *prove* I'm wrong? **2)** In general, when having problems to test your code you usually also have problems to reuse/modify your code as your program grows. And BTW: didn't you do the same (but for the test code)? **3)** there are only few cases where final is a *proper* use. Putting it anywhere without a specific reason is not *proper* even by means of "effective java". **4)** It tells a lot about you that you consider important OO principles being "buzzwords".

Comment: 1) Yes, I can prove you are wrong by simply pointing out that JMockit and JaCoCo, in recent versions, do work fine together (to the best of my knowledge). In other words, the fact that both of these tools do "alter the bytecode at runtime" does not mean that they will not work together.

Comment: 2) Yes, testability (ease of testing) is fundamentally the same as maintainability (ease of modifying/evolving the code). But ease of testing has nothing to do with methods being `final`, `private`, or `static`, or with objects being directly instantiated with `new` as opposed to being injected.

Comment: 3) No. In good API design (see also the "Practical API Design" and "API Design for C++" books) you declare *most* classes as `final`, as they won't be designed to be used as base classes. And when designing a base class, there usually are `protected` and `public` methods that need to be made `final` (for example, when applying the "Template Method" pattern from the GoF book). And "Effective Java" says in item 17 to "Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it" (meaning, make the class `final` by default).

Comment: 4) No, it tells a lot about *you* that you just throw these concepts around instead of actually understanding them and applying them where they actually are applicable. Look, I read (nearly) all the books, and I can describe every concept in my own words. And I can write any test just as easily whether the code uses Dependency Injection or not, has `static`/`final` or not, and so on - these things are not "untestable" by themselves.